# How to use SQLite Windows8.1 binary in a Windows8 app?

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-8.1

How can I use SQLite Windows8.1 version in my Windows8 app, so as to provide compatibility with both Window8 and Windows8.1 platforms? I tried referencing the new beta version of SQLite Windows8.1 in VS2012, but it would not accept the dll as valid dll/assembly? 
Do I have to create 2 vesions of the app, for both Windows8 and Windows8.1?

Answer (score 0):

A version of an app build for windows 8 will also work on windows 8.1 but a version build for windows 8.1 will not work on windows 8 (and this is independent of Sqlite).

Comment: I agree, but the problem that i'm currently facing is that the SQLite binary for Windows8.1, is not getting accepted in my Windows8 solution.

Comment: Why don't you just use the windows 8 SQLite binary for the windows 8 solution? Even if the SQLite binary is different, your database will still be compatible with both (as it would be compatible with any other sqlite implementation).